# Append Relation Count while using select in eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

So i have a query where i want to select specific columns and relation count on a model.

Something like this

```php
$posts = Post::withCount('comments')->select('title', 'content')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post->comments_count // this is not available because of select in query
}
```

Now when I use select in the query `comments_count` is no longer available. There is `$appends` option on the model where I can do something like `$appends = ['comments_count']` on the Post model but it will not work. Any idea how to append the data and use the select on model while querying using eloquent.

there is `$withCount` option on the model as well but it will lazy load while querying comments with post (i.e. inverse relation query).

Comment: What's wrong with the query you posted? It already looks functional.

Comment: comment_count is not available i.e. $post->comments_count

Comment: That's because it's a count for each comment. `$post[0]->comments_count.`. I've written an answer explaining this in more detail.

Comment: Simply put `withCount()` after the `select()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem if that `withCount('comments')` will generate the `comments_count` for each post.

Also, the `select()` overrides the previous `withCount()`. Simply change the order.

```php
$posts = Post::select('title', 'content')->withCount('comments')->get();
```

```php
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->comments_count;
}
```

If you want the global count, you'll need to use a collection method to sum all the counts.

```php
echo $posts->sum('comments_count');
```